# Trivial conversion

Tags: java

How can I convert the value returned by  `System.getProperty("line.separator");` to its string representation.

For instance, if the value is `"\n"`  I would like to have the string formed by the characters:  `['\' + 'n']`, if the value is `"\r\n"` => `['\','r','\','n']`does it make sense?

Some very trivial ideas come to my mind, I would like to know different ones.

**edit**

Doh!!.. after a little thinking ( very little indeed ) I came up with the obvious:

```
String  lineSeparatorRepresentation 
      = System.getProperty("line.separator").equals("\n")?"\\n":"\\r\\n";
```

Comment: Are you looking to print the string or to use it as a value in your program?

Comment: @justkt To print the value...

Comment: Are you wanting a solution for just this problem or should it be more general? As far as I know, there are only three strings which could possibly be returned by that method, so you might as well just make a Map<String, String> of them.

Comment: @mmyers What's the other? ... BTW I **KNOW** you're going to hate me, but I liked mmyers better :P ... no wait, don't kill me :)

Comment: The other is "\r", which is what Macs used to use before OSX (if I have my facts straight). And weren't you the one who asked me to use my real name?

Comment: Ohh... me ? ... mmh ... noooh... it was .. another ... ¬¬ ... run!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [escapeJava](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava-java.lang.String-) method of Apache Commons Lang's StringEscapeUtils class. If you don't want to depend on Commons Lang just for this, see their [source code](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=commons-lang.git;a=blob;f=src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.java;h=a244847f44e8209143eb623f59cc2d72d85c9baa;hb=HEAD#l454) for how they implement it – since the set of possible escapes are so low, it's just a small lookup table.

Comment: On a second thought, I might use other conversions for other parts of my program.. so +1 ... I'll accept in a couple of minutes

Answer (score 2):

Just convert each of the possible results into their respective strings.  If the result is `\n`, then convert to `\\n`, etc.  For a general solution, see `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava`: http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

```
lineSeparatorRepresentation.split("(?<=\\G.{1})");
```